# Print from a list

Tags: python, loops, date

I have a list of products with their preorder dates. However their dates are formatted  like this `20220627`. The last two numbers is the day, the following two the month and last four the year. The result I want to obtain is to get from this given number the date in **mm/dd/yyyy +hour** format, like this  `06/27/2022 12:00 AM`. I wrote the script to get the result I want, but only for one date and not multiple because I am getting this error

```
can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

The original code I wrote is this one:

```
dates = ("20220627")

year = dates[:4]
month = dates[4:6]
day = dates[6:]
hour = "12:00 AM"
result = month + "/" + day + "/" + year + " " + hour

print(result)
```

**Answer**
I found a way to do what I wanted with this script in case someone looks for something similar.

```
dates = ["20220627", "20210824", "20190306", "20180120", "20210512"]


for date in dates:
    year = date[:4]
    month = date[4:6]
    day = date[6:]
    hour = "12:00 AM"
    result = month + "/" + day + "/" + year + " " + hour
    print(result)
```

Comment: `dates` is a tuple, not a string. You can loop over items in a tuple or a list with `for item in dates:`

Comment: @tripleee this is actually a string, the comma is missing ;)

Comment: Code works fine for me: https://ideone.com/vCaocg

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? The standard library has the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module with functions designed specifically for date format conversion.

Answer (score 1):

The following example should help you:

```
r = []
dates = ("20220627","20220827","20220927","20211028")
for date in dates:
  r.append(date[4:6] + "/" + date[6:] + "/" + date[:4] + " " + "12:00 AM")
print(r)
```

Comment: The OP wanted to loop over several date strings and convert them.

Comment: I would go with something like `r = [datetime.strptime(f'{date} 12:00 AM', '%Y%m%d %H:%M %p').strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p') for date in dates]`, to be more _Pythonic_, or even skip `strftime()` altogether and just keep the `datetime` objects. The conversion could be done when needed, later in the code.